# [FireDAC][Phys][FB] file is not a valid database

Tags: delphi, firebird, delphi-xe7, firedac

I have a problem when accessing a GDB-DataBase via the FireDAC.FB-Driver.
The strange thing here is, that if I set up the connection at designtime, everything works fine with

`DriverID = FB`

`Server = 127.0.0.1`

`Protocol = TCPIP`

If I try the same connection params at runtime however it gives me a `[FireDAC][Phys][FB] file is not a valid database`-Error.

Units `FireDAC.Phys.FB` `FireDAC.Phys.FBDef` are both included. I even tried to set all possible dll-Files as `VendorLib`, but it doesn't change anything.

I know *.GDB is usually a InterBase-DataBase, but I have a FireBird-Server running, and to my understanding access via FB-Driver should work, since it does when specifying the connection at designtime.

Firebird-Server-Version is 2.5.3.26778 32-Bit

DelphiVersion is XE7

**Additional Edit:** ODS of the DataBase-File is 11.2 (Firebird 2.5/InterBase 7.5)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please show your runtime configuration from the FDDatabase
do you use fbclient.dll?

Comment: @Fritzw FDDataBase? I only know about FDConnection.

Comment: But they are as I stated above, Just imagine a Connection.Params.Add('...') around the params.

Comment: sorry yes i mean FDConnection
and you can do a query in the IDE?

Comment: If it's an InterBase database, use IB driver. There are warnings saying you should not be using FB driver to connect to an IB database in help.

Comment: InterBase 7.5 and Firebird 2.5 **are not compatible** for databases above ODS 10. Make sure you don't confuse the two. They may share a common history, but it is better if you consider them two entirely different products.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although InterBase and Firebird have a common heritage and share a lot of terminology, they **are not the same**. Since Firebird 1.5, the ODS versioning has diverged. Even though Firebird 1.5 and InterBase 6.1 both have ODS 10.1, these ODS versions are different and not compatible, more so for Firebird 2.5 and InterBase 7.5 (which both have an ODS version 11.2).

So if you try to open an InterBase 7.5 database with Firebird 2.5 **it will not work** and Firebird will report that the database is invalid (and vice versa InterBase will report a similar error if you try to open a Firebird database).

On a technical level this is achieved in Firebird by masking the ODS version so they are distinct from the version of InterBase:

> **`Hds_ods_version`**: Two bytes, unsigned. Bytes 0x12 and 0x13 on the page. The ODS major version for the database. The format of this word is the ODS major version ANDed with the Firebird flag of 0x8000. In the example below, the value is 0x800b for ODS version 11. The minor ODS version is held elsewhere in the header page - see `hdr_ods_minor` below.

From: [Inside a Firebird Database → Database Header Page - Type 0x01](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/fbint-page-1.html)

Comment: The answer to this question as written now is still, use IB driver to connect to your database, no matter what ODS is used. I'm saying so, because I'm finding wrong to use FB driver expecting IB databases on input, in general (even if they were compatible). This answer is nicely written, but answers the question about ODS compatibility (which in turn has nothing to do with FireDAC).

Comment: @TLama The driver is not directly relevant to the problem: the problem is that the database **server** doesn't understand the file format (ODS). Both drivers will probably support the old version 10 connection protocol, so at least in theory an IB driver could connect to a FB server and a FB driver to an IB server. Reading the database file is done by the server, not the driver.

Comment: Oh, I see your point now. Taking back... [deleting my comment(s)] This question has nothing to do with FireDAC then. It narrows down to if it's possible to connect to an IB database (with certain ODS) from Firebird.